# Как определить состояние setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет. Допустим, есть код:

```
let interval = setInterval(() => doSomething(), 3000);
```

Чтобы остановить исполнение `setInterval`, нужно сделать `clearInterval(interval);`

**Вопрос:** а как, собственно, определить, работает ли ещё setInterval, или он уже прекратил свою работу?

`console.log(interval)` что во время работы, что уже после clearInterval показывает одно и то же число - 69. После перезагрузки страницы оно может измениться.

Comment: он работает между вызовами `setInterval` и `clearInterval`, или `setInterval` и перезагрузкой страницы

Comment: interval - это просто рандомный id интервала. Что-то мешает задать переменную intervalCleard = false; и выставлять ему значение true параллельно с clearInterval(), ну или interval = 0; Для чего вообще требуется это отслеживать?

Comment: @MedvedevDev оформите, как ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let interval = setInterval(() => doSomething(), 3000);
// interval - принимает id интервала (генерируется случайно, любое целое число > 0)
```

На сколько мне известно, отслеживать можно только одним способом:

```js
let intervalID = setInterval(function(){}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
  clearTimeout(intervalID); // Отменяем
  intervalID = null; // Следом задаем id значение false/null/undefined/0 (кому как нравится)
}, 3000);

// Просто для вывода состояния
const statusIntervalID = setInterval(function() {
  if(intervalID) { // Проверяем активен ли интервал
    console.log('Interval is active');
  } else {
    clearInterval(statusIntervalID);
    console.log('Interval cleared');
  }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет прямого способа сделать то, что вы ищете. Вместо этого вы можете установить `timer` `false` при каждом вызове `clearInterval`:

```
// Start timer
var timer = setInterval(fncName, 1000);

// End timer
clearInterval(timer);
timer = false;
```

Теперь `timer` либо будет ложным , либо будет иметь значение в данный момент времени, поэтому вы можете просто проверить

```
if (timer)
    ...
```

Если вы хотите инкапсулировать это в класс:

```
function Interval(fn, time) {
    var timer = false;
    this.start = function () {
        if (!this.isRunning())
            timer = setInterval(fn, time);
    };
    this.stop = function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = false;
    };
    this.isRunning = function () {
        return timer !== false;
    };
}

var i = new Interval(fncName, 1000);
i.start();

if (i.isRunning())
    // ...

i.stop();
```

Источник: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679141](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679141/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-var-is-using-setinterval)